# How to change color in lstlisting (LaTeX) if the first symbol is $?

Tags: listings

By formatting command-line snippets with LaTeX lstlisting, I want to separate input commands from their outputs as follows:

In the command-line snippet:

```
$date
Sat Jun  1 14:31:01 CEST 2019
```

`$date` has to be in blue

`Sat Jun  1 14:31:01 CEST 2019` has to be in black

So the idea is to find all strings with the `$` first symbol and colorize them.

I've search through usual commands as `string` or `comment` with rudimentary regexp but without luck. Is it really possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```tex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily,
        morecomment={[l][\color{blue}]{\$}},]
        $date
        Sat Jun  1 14:31:01 CEST 2019
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The setting `morecomment={[l][\color{blue}]{\$}}` treats `$` as a character used to start a single line code "comment". Please search for "morecomment" in the listings manual for more details.

[image]